# Facebook, iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios5, facebook-ios-sdk

I am currently making a Facebook application for iOS that pulls the profile feed and puts it in a UITableView.

Right Now When the View Loads:

```
 [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andDelegate:self];
```

and in -(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result, i have:

```
NSArray *messagesFBData = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
NSMutableArray *friendIds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:messagesFBData.count];
NSMutableArray *fromData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:messagesFBData.count];
NSMutableArray *imagesLocal = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:messagesFBData.count];
for (int x = 0; x < messagesFBData.count; x++) {
    if ([(NSDictionary *)[messagesFBData objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"message"] != nil) {

        [friendIds addObject:[((NSDictionary*)[messagesFBData objectAtIndex:x]) objectForKey:@"message"]];
        NSLog(@"loop Log: %@", [(NSDictionary *)[messagesFBData objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"message"]);
        [fromData addObject:[((NSDictionary*)[messagesFBData objectAtIndex:x]) objectForKey:@"from"]];
        NSLog(@"%@", [((NSDictionary*)[messagesFBData objectAtIndex:x]) objectForKey:@"from"] );
        NSDictionary *fromDataDictionary = [fromData objectAtIndex:x]; 
        [imagesLocal addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture", [fromDataDictionary objectForKey:@"id"]]]]]];
            NSLog(@"facebook ID: %@", [fromDataDictionary objectForKey:@"id"]);
    } else  
         {
             NSLog(@"Nil Called");                 
         }

}

// don't forget to call loadData for your tableView
messages = friendIds;
images = imagesLocal;
NSLog(@"Equalized");
self.facebookTableView.delegate = self;
NSLog(@"Delegate Set");
[facebookTableView reloadData];
```

images is a global array, so i can access it in -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath.

so in -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath, i have:

```
NSLog(@"Cell For Row Called");
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"messageCell"];
NSString *story = [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = story;

UIImage *image = [images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.imageView.image = image;

cell.alpha = 1;
return cell;
```

So the question I am having a horrible time with is when a user posts a picture or video on the wall, how do i handle that? I would like to display the image/video in the tableview itself. Right Now, it just crashes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Virindh Borra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At what point is it crashing? Did you place any breakpoints in the code? When you add the UIImage to the imagesLocal array, are you the path at "https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture" contains a valid image?

Comment: the point it crashes right now is when the messages array loads up the wall post with an image with but there is a picture rather than an "message" object that Facebook returns. the https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture is what i set the tableviews default image view's image as, because thats the image of who posted the post.

Comment: Are you saying the array contains both strings and images, and your code is currently only handling the case for strings? If I understand it right, you can do something like:
if ([element isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
//Handle case for Facebook message
}
else if ([element isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]){
//Handle case for Facebook image
}