# Custom Subview of UIImage in TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, facebook-graph-api

Right now i am trying to pull an image from Facebook , and putting it in a table view.

I don't want to use the default image view of the cell. because the image size can vary.

How do I make an image view and put it in the cell and then adjust the cell height so that it matches the image height?

Any Help what so ever would be greatly helpful.

Thanks,
Virindh Borra

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the height of a row in the `UITableViewDelegate` method `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. It is possible that with using that method you can use the built-in `imageView` property of `UITableViewCell`

Edit:
If there is some reason that the `imageView` property won't let you do what you want, I would consider making a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Thanks, but I am not trying to use the default image view.

Comment: Why not? Is there something more you want to do with it than just have a fixed size?  I have edited my answer with another possible solution.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I am looking for, as I am already using the default image view for something else. How would I make a subclass of uiimageview and add it the cell?

Comment: You don't need to subclass UIImageView. In fact, you probably shouldn't. What you should do is subclass UITableViewCell and add another image view property to it.

Comment: Thank you so much, but how would I do that, are there any resources you can point to Or can you show me some sample code?

Comment: Protip: try a quick Google search. [Here is the second result](http://giorgiocalderolla.com/2011/04/16/customizing-uitableviewcells-a-better-way/) from searching "UITableViewCell"

Comment: That helps, but it doesn't need to be tht customized, to get a look at my code/ what I'm talking about, here is my other question with my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489494/facebook-ios-sdk

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with the following:

***ViewController.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ResizingCell.h"
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet ResizingCell *Cell;
@end
```

***ViewController.m***

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize Cell;
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}
- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [(ResizingCell *)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] getHeight];
}
- (ResizingCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ResizingCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ResizingCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [self Cell];
        [self setCell:nil];
    }
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", [indexPath row]]];
    [cell setImage:image];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

***ResizingCell.h***

```
#define BUFFER 20
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ResizingCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView;
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image;
- (float)getHeight;
@end
```

***ResizingCell.m***

```
#import "ResizingCell.h"
@implementation ResizingCell
@synthesize myImageView;
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image {
    [[self myImageView] setImage:image];
    // Because the width will be important, I'd recommend setting it here...
    [[self myImageView] setFrame:CGRectMake(currFrame.origin.x, currFrame.origin.y, image.size.width, currFrame.size.height)];
}
- (float)getHeight {
    return (2 * BUFFER) + [[self myImageView] image].size.height;
}
@end
```

The code should be pretty self-explanatory. When I test it with a really tall image, it changes height appropriately.